# Time restriction on Salah and replacement (قضاء) Salah

Tags: salat, time

Is there any specific time in which we should perform replacement (قضاء) Salah? and Is there any restriction on particular time on which we should not perform Salah?

Comment: related question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/625/does-tartib-apply-to-delayed-fardh-salats

Comment: @goldPseudo one of my question is answered by that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no restriction on time for Qada' (قضاء) prayer.  When you remember that you have not made a salat yet, then you must try to make it right away.

> Qatada narrated on the authority of Anas b. Malik that the Apostle of
> Allah (may peace be upon him) said: He who forgets the prayer, or he
> slept (and it was omitted), its expiation is (only) that he should
> observe it when he remembers it.
>
> وَحَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ الْمُثَنَّى، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الأَعْلَى،
> حَدَّثَنَا سَعِيدٌ، عَنْ قَتَادَةَ، عَنْ أَنَسِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ، قَالَ
> قَالَ نَبِيُّ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ مَنْ نَسِيَ صَلاَةً أَوْ
> نَامَ عَنْهَا فَكَفَّارَتُهَا أَنْ يُصَلِّيَهَا إِذَا ذَكَرَهَا ‏"‏
>
> [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:684c)

Salat should not be made in five particular times:

1. After Fajr salat until the sun is about a spears length in the eyes sight, meaning about a third of an hour.
2. The time in which the sun is rising until it is about a spears length, meaning about a third of an hour after the rising of the sun.
3. When the sun is exactly in the middle of the sky, meaning 3 or 4 minutes before Zuhr.
4. When the sun becomes yellow until it's setting.
5. After Asr until the sun has set.

Source: Al Fiqh Al Maliki Al Muyassar By Dr. Wahbat Azzuhayli