# Is there a time limit for making up a salat?

Tags: salat, salat-qada

When missing a *salat*, is there any time limit after which you can't make up this *salat* anymore?

Comment: At least the last part of your question is a part of my answer here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/what-do-i-do-if-i-missed-joined-prayers there's no limit time, you'll be asked to pray them as long as you haven't yet and remember them, some scholars say you don't have to but should do your best in praying nafl as a kind of expiation...

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thanks, and to be sure I understand the meaning of making up prayers _by pairs_ in the answer (if one missed more than 5 prayers), that means that, for example, you pray the Asr at time, and then you make up the missed Asr of the day before ?

Comment: Yes but if they were more then one you may pray the actual 'asr then two older 'asr prayers (this is the pair I meant) or more as much as you can always by pairs that means 2 times, 4 times 6 times etc.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Ok, but, if I pray the subh and then I miss all the day prayers from Dohr, and no possibility to make them up that day ? can I do each missed salat after the salat in time next day ? (Dohr + missed Dohr, Asr + missed Asr... etc)

Comment: well the hadith which allows or is the basis for qada' says you can pray them once you remember, so how exactly you do it is up to you, you shouldn't pray qada' of many prayers if this way you may miss an to pray an actual prayer on time that's the most important. You could say that as far as there's no clear rule the rulings are recommendation from the madhabs, some may say keep the order, others may say pray the prayers at any time, others pray the missed 'asr prayer on the time of the actual 'asr.

Comment: You may also consult this post i just found http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/625/does-tartib-apply-to-delayed-fardh-salats

Comment: The second half of this question is a clear duplicate of http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/625/22; I have removed it so this question is focussed only on the part that is not already covered there.