# Is reading kaza salah allowed the next day?

Tags: salat, salat-qada

I live in Europe and my work commute is long, the only prayer I have time to read on time are Fajr, Maghrib (in summers) and Isha. The rest I have to read as Kaza. Sometimes I am so out of energy that I cannot do it and so 4 out of 5 are missed.

My question is can I read kaza namaz next day for the previous day instead of feeling guilty? Is there any Hadith about people unable to perform Namaz on time and reading as soon as possible for missed one (like next day)

Comment: I'd wonder if this question has not been covered many times on the site. There are different opinions on whether or how to pray qada' or what to do instead and there's a sahih hadith telling us we must pray a prayer we missed as soon as we remeber it. So yes you can and some may say you must pray qada' no matter if it is the next day, week, month or year...

Comment: See for example [What do I do if I missed joined prayers](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/what-do-i-do-if-i-missed-joined-prayers) , [Does tartib apply to delayd fardh salats?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/625/does-tartib-apply-to-delayed-fardh-salats) and [Does a Muslim has to pray all the prayers that he left out](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33/does-a-muslim-have-to-pray-all-the-prayers-that-he-left-out)

Comment: @Nofel Is it not possible for you to pray while travelling? The Sahaba in some instances are known to have prayed on their camels when the conditions were not right to stop or if they wanted to pray nafl.

Answer (score -1):

There is no prayer after its time unless you are in a state of unconciousness/unintentional sleep or travelling. Even while travelling you have to make intention of joining the prayers during the time of prayer. Travelling has a minimum distance of above 89 kms.

Compensation /kaza is offered only when a person completely forgets about the prayer or sleeps through non-delibrately or is unconcious.

Your situation doesn't fall in above 3 categories mentioned. You have to pray them at their specific times and do lot of good deeds in addition to timely prayers.

Comment: This is one single fiqh perspective and your answer lacks evidences to support your claim. It basically is not even representing the view of one of the four sunni schools of jurisprudence by any means.