# I would like know how to perform 'kazaa-e-umri'?

Tags: salat, salat-qada

I have perform a salah / namaz  at mosque during ramdan.I feel that I want to do kaza for recent all namaz. I would like to know procedure as well as ayat can recite during namaz. Thank you.

Comment: actually I have listen bayan. Prayers are mendatory you need to do it any way if you left you need to do qada. Used term 'qada-e-umri'.

Comment: The term qada' umri sounds weird, as it means qada' for your whole life! It would make sense if you are very old or about to die!

Comment: Sister @Jamila I heard that in takrir that's why used that term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prayers are in fact mandatory and they are the first thing -among the worship- on which we are accountable on the day of judgement.

> The first of his actions for which a servant of Allah will be held accountable on the Day of Resurrection will be his prayers. If they are in order, then he will have prospered and succeeded: and if they are wanting, then he will have failed and lost. If there is something defective in his obligatory prayers, the Lord (glorified and exalted be He) will say: See if My servant has any supererogatory prayers with which may be completed that which was defective in his obligatory prayers. Then the rest of his actions will be judged in like fashion. ([Riyadu As-Saliheen](https://sunnah.com/qudsi40/9))

Scholars are in consensus that fard (obligatory) prayers are a due on every Muslim. But they hold three major opinions on whether or not one must make them up if one misses them and have a consensus that this requires a making repentance (tawbah) first and starting to pray and no more leaving it. The above hadith shows one opinion which is one may "correct" his mistake by praying more optional prayers (but no more missing the actual fard prayers too). The second opinion is basically held by two scholars namely ibn Hazm first and later adapted by ibn Taymiyyah which is that there's no qada' of fard prayers pretending that there's no backup for this and that prayer is only valid if prayed on time the only exception is if one slept or forgot to pray and missed to pray on time based on the hadith:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "If anyone forgets a prayer he should pray that prayer when he remembers it. There is no expiation except to pray the same." Then he recited: "Establish prayer for My (i.e. Allah's) remembrance." (20.14). ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:597))

The wording that there's no "expiation except to pray the same" however lead the majority of scholars (the 4 sunni madhhabs and apparently shi'a too) to say that one may pray qada' prayers and they say that you may do it as follows as long as you have less or equal than one day of prayers you should pray them and pray your actual prayer later. Else if you had 6 or more prayers to make up you should pray them after praying your actual fard, it is recommended to pray them two by two if you have to make up many of them (this is explained in [What do I do if I missed joined prayers?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/what-do-i-do-if-i-missed-joined-prayers) and [Does Tartib apply to delayed fardh salats?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/625/does-tartib-apply-to-delayed-fardh-salats)).
Nevertheless some scholars also recommend you to give an effort in praying optional prayers too while other say as long as you have this due you should concentrate on that.

If you are uncertain how much prayers you have missed you should do a good guess and hope that you will have paid your due when finishing it therefore it would be best to put some effort in nafl prayers.

Comment: Thank you for detailed description. I will word with imam sheb also for the same.