# Waking up after Fajr-prayer and after Churuq (sunrise)

Tags: salat-qada

I've learnt from my stepmum that one should pray first Subh and then Fajr if one wakes up after the Fajr-prayer and after Churuq (sunrise). If one wakes up at Fajr-time you should pray first Fajr and then Subh.

I've tried to search for an answer [here](https://islamqa.info/en/65941) and [here](https://www.al-islam.org/search/site/Fajr%20and%20subh) but to no avail.

I wonder if this a right way to do so or maybe I need to find a way to wake up before Churuq? The reason why I pray Fajr sometimes later is because of the short time interval between the Isha-prayer and the Fajr-prayer (4 hours). I need to sleep at least 6 hours straight otherwise I won't be productive in my school work.

Source:

https://islamqa.info/en/65941

https://www.al-islam.org/search/site/Fajr%20and%20subh

Comment: What do you mean by Subh?

Comment: @Crimson sobh is the fard prayer on fajr time.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yes, but the OP seems to have a different understanding: "...one should pray first Subh and then Fajr ...". How can one pray Subh first and then Fajr when they are the same thing?!

Comment: @Medi1Saif: I think you meant sunnah prayer as Subh isn't compulsory to pray.

Comment: @Crimson: Subh and Fajr are not the same. Fajr is fard (compulsory) to pray and Subh isn't.

Comment: No sobh is the fard and fajr is the sunnah some call both fajr.

Comment: Oh, I just found this out. According to [this site](https://islamqa.info/en/79345) it's neither. Apparently subh is synonymously to fajr. So what I'm talking about is the nafila/ sunnah prayer.

Comment: A reason is that the fard prayer is a due on you so you have to pray it while the sunnah is optional, so you may leave it. In fact it is the more known opinion in the Maliki madhhab the other one exclaimed by imam Malik is praying fajr then sobh -in order-.

Comment: @AnonymousI Fajr salat has 4 raka'ah. 2 sunnah and 2 fard. Are you referring to this sunnah prayer?

Comment: Also, if you intentionally wake up after Fajr time, there  are three opinions. Also qada prayer is prayed in same order. So the difference in order you're referring to is baseless. See: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48740/i-would-like-know-how-to-perform-kazaa-e-umri/48749#48749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it should be like this all the time. Even if one prays Fajr on time and prays the Subh prayer. One should first pray Subh (sunnah prayer (2 rak'ahs)) and then Fajr (fard prayer (compulsory)).

Source:

https://islamqa.info/en/33779