# How to make up for decades of missed salah,

Tags: salat, practical-islam, salat-qada

I have not prayed regularly for decades of my life. I am really trying hard to become regular now, using salah timimg apps.  How do I make up for all the thousands of missed salahs?

Comment: See for example [I would like to know how to perform kazaa-e-umri?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48740/i-would-like-know-how-to-perform-kazaa-e-umri) and [What do I do if I missed joined prayers?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/what-do-i-do-if-i-missed-joined-prayers) and many other posts with the tag [tag:salat-qada]

Answer (score -3):

Asslamu-alaikum dear,
   The method is very simple. Suppose you have missed prayers of last 10 years. i.e., April 08, 2010. Then you will have to offer exactly one Salah after every salah from today, i.e, April 08, 2020 till April 08, 2030. (up to next 10 years).
  Also, you will have to keep in mind the salah you are offering, i.e. called as 'Niyat'.